# Getting "Object references an unsaved transient instance " instead of "foreign key constraint exception" for a nullable foreign key field

Tags: jpa, kotlin, foreign-keys

I have an Entity A which has a nullable foreign key field 'field1' which references the primary key of entity B. If I am making a post request with a field value which is not present in Entity B .I am expecting foreign key exception instead I am getting object references an unsaved transient instance exception. If the 'field1' is made as notnull expected exception for foreignkey is coming. Wanted to know what is the relationship between nullable field and foreignkey constraint

Have tried with

```
1)      @ManyToOne(cascade = arrayOf(CascadeType.All))
        @JoinColumn(name ="book",referencedColumnName ="book_id")
        var book: Book? = null,

when I am giving this..instead of checking foreign key constraint, it was trying to add book entity also into DB

2)      @ManyToOne(cascade = arrayOf(CascadeType.All))
        @JoinColumn(name ="book",referencedColumnName ="book_id",nullable=true, insertable=false,updatable=false)
        var book: Book? = null,

3)      @ManyToOne(optional=false,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumn(name ="book",referencedColumnName ="book_id")
        var book: Book? = null,

4)      @ManyToOne(optional=false,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name ="book",referencedColumnName ="book_id")
        var book: Book? = null,


But whatever I try I am getting the same transientobject exception ..only if the field "book" was given a not null constraint in db, it is throwing foreign key exception.
```

```
please find the code
    @Entity
    @Table(name ="student")
    class Student(

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    var id: Long? = -1,

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name ="book",referencedColumnName ="book_id")
    var book: Book? = null,
        )


    @Entity
    @Table(name ="book")
    class Book(

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "book_id")
    var book_id: Long? = -1

    )
```

Excepecting :
"could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [book]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement"

Actually getting :
"org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation : Student.book -> Book; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation : Student.book -> Book

Comment: Can you show me the code which is saving the Student?

Comment: `
fun createStudent(student:com.test.model.Student): com.test.model.Student {
        return buildStudent(this.studentRepository.save(com.test.Entity.Student(stduent.id, stduent.book)))
    }`
Repository is implemented with jpa
`
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.*
interface StudentRepository : JpaRepository<Student, Int>
    }`